# Error deploying Grails 2.0.4 to Glassfish 3.1.2 Server

Tags: grails, spring-security, glassfish

I am using Spring Security Core 1.2.7.3 plugin and am getting this error when trying to deploy:

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception
 is     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while
setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting 
bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while    
setting 
bean property 'propertie .... msg.seeServerLog
```

The application works fine when I run it from inside netbeans, but when I try to deploy it I am getting the error. I have tried cleaning, and uncommenting the `'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16'` code in the dependencies in the BuildConfig.groovy file. I am using an Oracle jdbc driver which I have installed inside my /lib folder.

I am guessing that this has something to do with the Oracle jdbc driver not being found.

update: I have added my production closure below

```
production {
    dataSource {
        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@MYSERVERNAME.com:xxxx:xxxxxxx"
        pooled = true
        properties {
           maxActive = -1
           minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
           timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
           numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
           testOnBorrow=true
           testWhileIdle=true
           testOnReturn=true
           validationQuery="SELECT 1"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `DataSource.groovy`, most likely there's something wrong in your `production` closure. When you run inside NetBeans you're probably using the development environment but when you build a war Grails uses the production environment.  You could try setting the `-Dgrails.env=production` flag inside the IDE to see if you run into the same problem.  If it works you know it's a problem with Glassfish, if it fails you know it's a problem with your environment configuration.

**Edit:**

Try adding this to your production closure:

```
driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
```

Or whichever dialect is appropriate for your version of Oracle.

Comment: Ok, I did as you said and got an error when setting the `-Dgrails.env=production flag` inside the IDE. I have edited my original post to include the production closure. Is there anything in the closure that you can see might be causing the issue?

Comment: Tried adding those and it is still broken. Maybe it is deeper than just the Datasource.groovy file?

Comment: I just commented out the Properties{} section and tried to run it - it seemed to run in production mode OK once I did this. I don't understand what the properties closure is doing, but I assume that this is for H2 db and not pertaining to Oracle jdbc? This seems to be the cause of the error. What should I have for properties for the oracle db?

Comment: It could be your validation SQL.  That would fail in Oracle, try `select 1 from dual` instead of just `select 1`

Comment: Yes `select 1 from dual` fixed the issue. This is my first app launch and my first time dealing with Oracle. Thank you so much for helping me isolate my issue. I really appreciate it!